# Form is not created inside while loop

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am newbie to asp.net . I learned that only one server side form could be used on a page. So.. due to functional requirement I have to create multiple forms . I did it with normal forms (without     `runat="server"` tag . I used while loop to create form. Counter is initialized to zero & incremented to a particular length. But after running page I found by viewing source on browser that first form tag was not there (that is made on counter value 0) and other forms were there (counter value greater than zero). For reference I am including my code

```
   <%
            int length = 0;
            while (postListLength > length)
            { %>
        <div class="View-Posts">

            <div class="View-Post-Content">
                <%=postList[length].PostContent %><br />
                <form method="post" action="CompletePost.aspx">
                <input type="hidden" name="RequestedId" value="<%=postList[length].PostId.ToString()%>" />
                <input type="submit" value="See More" />
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        <%
length++;
    }
        %>
```

Then I made another asp page without loop only one form there also I got the same problem.

**But the inner content of form is there like textbox etc. only form tag is not there for first form**
Any help will be appreciable

Comment: You can only have 1 form - period. You can't have multiple forms on the same page so you need to find a better solution.

Comment: But after 1st form. Later form are being generated on Counter > 0 and this is normal HTML form not asp.net Server side form

Comment: There is not difference between server side form and html form. The server side form renders as a normal form. Check your page's source. Your page will break if you have multiple forms. Please use a different approach.

Comment: Check out this article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx#S4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx#S4)